# State of the art selfhealing and selfprotection in DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, db2

at the moment I'm writing a paper and I need some input about the state of the art of selhealing and selfprotection in DBMSs. Does somebody read some interesting articles or books about this topics in the last few month? Doesnt matter which DBMS you have read about.

Regards

Comment: You could also try: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this: [Automatic Page Repair During a Database Mirroring Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677167.aspx).